Apply specific function to column by groups in R
Let's say I have the following dataset:
data <- data.frame(code=1:16,
                   region=c('10', '20', '10', '20', '20', '20', '10', '20', '20', '10', '20', '10', '20', '10', '10', '20'),
                   value=c(1, 101, 5, 205, 206, 205, 7, 205, 204, 6, 205, 4, 206, 5, 15, 305))

I want to apply the winsorize function from the datawizard package to the value column, grouping the observations by region.
What would be the correct way to do it?

data %>% mutate(value1 = winsorize(value), .by = region)

or with(data, ave(value, region, FUN=datawizard::winsorize))

To ensure the three families are represented. The data.table way would be data[, vals_winsorize := winsorize(value), by = region] if you want a new column. Or data[, value:= winsorize(value), by = region] if you want to modify in place

Translated @Ronak Shah's comment under the question into an answer:
data <- data.frame(code=1:16,
                   region=c('10', '20', '10', '20', '20', '20', '10', '20', '20', '10', '20', '10', '20', '10', '10', '20'),
                   value=c(1, 101, 5, 205, 206, 205, 7, 205, 204, 6, 205, 4, 206, 5, 15, 305))
library(datawizard)
library(dplyr)
data %>%
 mutate(value1 = winsorize(value), .by = region)

